In-memory, replicated cache for Apache Flink tasks
Im processing a stream that needs to be transformed based on an inventory data. Inherently, the inventory data will be big (dont have exact figure) and will have A LOT of reads and very few writes.
Let's assume I have 3 task managers with 1 slot for each.
How can my transform operator running on 3 different machines use an in-memory, replicated cache?

Would it be possible to partition the stream and the cache by the same key, to avoid needing to replicate the cache and make the solution more scalable?

Hmm not sure. The number of keys is somewhere between 50K-100K.

To give you a little bit more context: the stream I’m trying to enrich consists of several 100K device ids. Ids allow me to join with inventory data which may have writes every once in a while. This is the inventory data I want to keep in-mem and replicate. I have been reading on broadcast pattern that may work. As per the pattern, I can broadcast my invt data to parallel streams. Thoughts?

If an inventory can be mapped to several device id's, it seems that the correct solution for you is the broadcast method. You write to the broadcast state each time an inventory has been changed, and read from it whenever you need to join with a device id.

Normally (with reasonable record size for the enrichment data) you can easily save 100s of K of unique records in state. Since you're joining enrichment data to your stream based on IDs, just use a KeyedCoProcessFunction.
Often the main challenge here is cold-start, where you want to first make sure your state (the enrichment data) is completely loaded before you start processing the data to be enriched. One simple solution is to first run your workflow in a special mode, where you have a dummy source for the streaming data. Once all of the enrichment data has been loaded, stop it with a savepoint, then restart in normal mode from that savepoint.

How do you propose I create the inventory stream as part of KeyedCoProcessFunction? A CDC stream using Debezium maybe?

Yes, that's the recommended approach. Otherwise you'd typically write a custom source that regularly queries the DB, and saves current high water mark in state (e.g. last modified timestamp from most recent successful query). But that's non-trivial to get right.
